# Writers.SE's Genre Q&A Contest!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion, contest

NaNoWriMo is in full swing, and that's the perfect opportunity to kick Writers.SE up a notch as well! So we're pleased to announce **Writers.SE's Genre Contest** - an event to beef up our site content with all things genre, with some awesome prizes!

### New to Writers.SE?

Welcome to the site! [Writers.SE](http://writers.stackexchange.com) is a Q&A site for writers of every stripe.

Writers.SE is *different* than other forums you may be familiar with. We have a unique, community-moderated Q&A format, which is worth getting to know a little. [Our site intro](https://writers.stackexchange.com/about) will get you started, our [help page](https://writers.stackexchange.com/help) is ever-handy, and if you've still got any questions about how things work here, please feel free to ask on our [Meta page](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com).

### Rules

This contest will run **from 14 November 2013 to 8 December 2013**, with midnight GMT as the cutoff at both ends.

At the end of the contest, we will give prizes to users based on a raffle. Users gain "raffle tickets" by asking questions and writing answers within the following tags:

[children](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children)
[comedy](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comedy)
[crime](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crime)
[erotica](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/erotica)
[fan-fiction](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fan-fiction)
[fantasy](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy)
[science-fiction](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction)
[historical](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical)
[horror](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror)
[mystery](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mystery)
[romance](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/romance)
[thriller](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thriller)
[young-adult](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/young-adult)

[Click here for all posts in the contest tags!](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children+or+comedy+or+crime+or+erotica+or+fan-fiction+or+fantasy+or+science-fiction+or+historical+or+horror+or+mystery+or+romance+or+thriller+or+young-adult)

Each question or answer awards you tickets towards the contest, based on the post’s score on the day of the drawing. An answer gets you 1 ticket for every five points in its score, and a question gets you 2 tickets for every five points!

In addition, you can earn tickets by promoting our site and spreading the word:

- 2 tickets for each Announcer badge gained during the contest, [(don't forget to use the url from "share" to qualify for this)](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/)
- 5 tickets for each Booster badge gained during the contest.
- 10 tickets for each Publicist badge gained during the contest.

**Drawings will be held on 10 December,** and we'll update this post / answers with a running leaderboard each week on Monday.

Sharing badges can be earned for ANY question/answer, regardless of when that post was made or what tag it is in.

Tickets for questions and answers can only be earned for posts created during the contest period. Posts made prior to the contest starting are not eligible.

### Other Rules:

- If your question is closed, it is disqualified.
- If your answer is deleted, it is disqualified.
- If you are found to be using sockpuppets or caught gaming the system, you will be disqualified.
- If you are suspended during the contest period, you are disqualified.
- We reserve the right to alter or append to these rules as circumstances arise during the event.
- Writers.SE moderators are not eligible to participate in the contest.

### Prizes

**Three swagwinners** will get writerly Stack Exchange swag!

**Two prizewinners** will win their choice between our two prize bundles:

- A selection of three writing books from our book list, OR
- A 1-year subscription to Duotrope, the market-tracking service!

**One grand-prize winner** wins two prize bundles!

### Prize Book List

- Books from any of the following series:

  - [*Genre Writing* Series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/116033-genre-writing-series), by Writer’s Digest
  - [*Elements of Fiction* Series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/67685-elements-of-fiction-writing), by Writer’s Digest
  - [*Write Great Fiction* Series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/70349-write-great-fiction), by Writer’s Digest
  - [*Howdunit* Series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/76228-howdunit-series), by Writer’s Digest
  - [*Science Fiction Writing* Series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/56501-science-fiction-writing-series), edited by Ben Bova
  - [*For Dummies* Series](http://www.dummies.com/store-search.html?query=writing), writing titles only
- [*On Writing*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439156816), by Stephen King
- [*Zen in the Art of Writing*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1877741094), by Ray Bradbury

NOTE: You can select books which are out of print; in this case, the prize may be a used copy.

Comment: Note - tickets have been tallied, winners will be posted soon!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### And Our Winners Are:

- **Swag Winners:** SF. , JMcAfreak, and Saint Georg.
- **Bundle Winners:** CLockeWork and Lauren Ipsum.
- **Grand Prize Winner:** Lauren Ipsum!

We will be getting in touch with all prizewinners soon.

Many, many thanks to everybody who participated, helped, and followed along. This has been a lot of fun; we've added some really nice content and livened up the question feed; and we've got some terrific new users.

Special thanks to Stack Exchange and to Tim Post, who made this happen!

Comment: Just a note - if your name is on this list, _please_ make sure that your profile contains a current e-mail address that you'll be certain to check. I'll be reaching out to folks and collecting information as early as Friday, likely Monday of next week. Congratulations to the winners, and thanks to everyone that participated! We got some really interesting questions and answers, and a few great new users. Good job everyone!

Comment: @TimPost: ...and thank you very much Tim for your efforts in this really interesting forum.

Comment: "Standback" I would like to thank you very much for guiding me kindly in this forum.

Comment: @TimPost: I replied your mail at Tuesday, 24th December, one day after your mentioned date at Monday, 23th December. I hope I don't lose my prize because of this late answer. If there is a problem please email me about it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @SaintGeorg No problem at all, I was off yesterday (and again today), I'll be contacting folks at the end of this week.

Comment: @TimPost: Thank you very much Tim. Excuse me for contacting you again.

Comment: Congrats to all the winners!

Answer (score 3):

Two notes so far, folks!

1. Share, share, share! Regulars on the site know this is the first major event we've organized for Writers.SE. This is our big opportunity to bring in new users, with a shiny event and a fun challenge. Let's make this count - so let your friends, your workshops, your writer blogs, know there's a cool contest going on. (If you'd like some text to share on your favorite blog, forum, or other online haunt, ping me and I'll help you out.)
2. I encourage all the site regulars to try and come up with a couple of questions appropriate for the contest. This is, to a large extent, a content generation event. Building up a good, diverse body of genre related questions is terrific for the contest, because it gives us critical mass, and provides newcomers with interesting content and with questions to answer. It's terrific for the site, because the more genre-related content we have, the more genre-related interest we'll get in the future. And it's terrific for you, because it gets you lots of shiny virtual raffle tickets :D

Answer (score 3):

Here's our final tally:

### Questions

- Saint Georg - 2

  - [How can I write a tragedy for children?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9403/how-can-i-write-a-tragedy-for-children) (2)
- Lauren Ipsum - 4

  - [When do I explain my created world scenario in a prologue vs. letting it unfold in the story?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9505/when-do-i-explain-my-created-world-scenario-in-a-prologue-vs-letting-it-unfold) (4)(2)
- CLockeWork - 2

  - [Can we enable readers to connect to far future humanity, without pretending they wouldn’t be different?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9480/can-we-enable-readers-to-connect-to-far-future-humanity-without-pretending-they) (2)
- Kit - 2

  - [Method for handling non-canonical fantasy fiction](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9633/method-for-handling-non-canonical-fantasy-fiction) (2)
- what - 2

  - [How explicit can violence and sex be in a YA novel?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9594/how-explicit-can-violence-and-sex-be-in-a-ya-novel) (2)

### Answers

- JMcAfreak - 1

  - [How do I avoid tech/social errors in near-future fiction?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9465/how-do-i-avoid-tech-social-errors-in-near-future-fiction/9471#9471) (1)
- Lauren Ipsum - 3

  - [Can we enable readers to connect to far future humanity, without pretending they wouldn’t be different?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9480/can-we-enable-readers-to-connect-to-far-future-humanity-without-pretending-they/9481#9481) (1)
  - [How explicit can violence and sex be in a YA novel?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9594/how-explicit-can-violence-and-sex-be-in-a-ya-novel/9597#9597) (1)
  - [Is having a specific town for a setting in a young-adult novel a bad thing?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9591/is-having-a-specific-town-for-a-setting-in-a-young-adult-novel-a-bad-thing/9592#9592) (1)
- SF. - 1

  - [When do I explain my created world scenario in a prologue vs. letting it unfold in the story?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9505/when-do-i-explain-my-created-world-scenario-in-a-prologue-vs-letting-it-unfold/9507#9507) (1)
- Dale Emery - 1

  - [Best way to convey an immediate change of scenery](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9391/best-way-to-convey-an-immediate-change-of-scenery/9394#9394) (1)
- what - 1

  - [Can we enable readers to connect to far future humanity, without pretending they wouldn’t be different?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9480/can-we-enable-readers-to-connect-to-far-future-humanity-without-pretending-they/9483#9483) (1)
- Seth Gordon - 1

  - [Can we enable readers to connect to far future humanity, without pretending they wouldn’t be different?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9480/can-we-enable-readers-to-connect-to-far-future-humanity-without-pretending-they/9487#9487) (1)
- Matt Ellen - 1

  - [Can I plug a loophole in my magic rules without rewriting the whole novel?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9582/can-i-plug-a-loophole-in-my-magic-rules-without-rewriting-the-whole-novel/9584#9584) (1)
- Alexander Winn - 1

  - [Method for handling non-canonical fantasy fiction](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9633/method-for-handling-non-canonical-fantasy-fiction/9637#9637) (1)
- hildred - 1

  - [Dripfeeding New Concepts to a Reader](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9570/dripfeeding-new-concepts-to-a-reader/9572#9572) (1)

We'll be holding the drawing during chat tonight! Here's the ticket numbers for the drawing:

```
1-2: Saint Georg
3-6: Lauren Ipsum
7-8: CLockeWork
9-10: Kit
11-12: what
13: JMcAfreak
14-16: Lauren Ipsum
17: SF.
18: Dale Emery
19: what
20: Seth Gordon
21: Matt Ellen
22: Alexander Winn
23: hildred
```

Comment: This search will net you most of the contest content:
`score:5 created:2013-11-14..2013-12-8 [science-fiction] or [historical] or [horror] or [mystery] or [romance] or [thriller] or [young-adult]` . Swap out the tag list to get the rest.